# How do I detect that an element within an *ngIf has loaded in order to execute code on it?

Tags: angular

I have two divs with components inside. On those divs, I have *ngIfs to toggle between the two. In my component.ts, I'm calling `.setAttribute` on each of those. The problem I have is that the components are coming back undefined at the time my code is executed.

For example:

```
<div *ngIf="something"><component-one some-attribute></component-one></div>
<div *ngIf="!something"><component-two some-attribute></component-two></div>
```

```
  updateAttribute() {
    this.componentOne = document.getElementsByTagName('component-one')[0];
    this.componentTwo = document.getElementsByTagName('component-two')[0];
    console.log(this.componentOne); // <- this is coming back undefined at this point.
    if (this.componentOne) {
      // so we're not making it into here.
      this.componentOne.setAttribute('some-attribute', this.someAttribute);
    }
    if (this.componentTwo) {
      this.componentTwo.setAttribute('some-attribute', this.someAttribute);
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to detect that the elements/components have loaded?

Comment: Use the variable something to check which component is toggled. Change if(this.componenet) to if(this.something)

Comment: why would you want to manipulate the DOM like this? Instead explain what you want to achieve and there would probably be "an angular way" to do it.

Comment: The reason is because this is a test application hosting a component that will be shared between applications, not all of whom are using angular. We're testing every possible case and I wondered if there was a way to accomplish this. This issue I'm having with checking if something exists is that if it doesn't at the right moment (which it never does), it doesn't come back to check again. What we ended up doing is using `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` - it just took some doing to override the CSS that usually makes that difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @output here and emit the function from child component.[You can get more about event emission here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Do you mean emitting something from ```componentOne``` to say that it exists? That may be possible, but what we were hoping to accomplish is a way to handle this outside of the components themselves. This will end up being a shared component between teams using different technologies. That could very well be a solution though.

Answer (score 1):

You are directly manipulating the DOM which is not recommended. There is a better Angular way to achieve this. But if you want to go with this:

```
updateAttribute() {
     if (this.something) {
         this.componentOne = document.getElementsByTagName('component-one')[0];
         this.componentOne.setAttribute('some-attribute', this.someAttribute);
     } else {
         this.componentTwo = document.getElementsByTagName('component-two')[0];
         this.componentTwo.setAttribute('some-attribute', this.someAttribute);
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue that ```document.getElementsByTagName('component-one)[0]``` comes back undefined at the time it executes.